# How can I integrate tensorboard visualization to tf.Estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I have classical TensorFlow code for recognizing handwritten digits https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py , using tf.Estimator. My question is comlicated and consists of two questions

1. Should I write tf.summary() for target variables in code to visualize data in Tensoboard just typing `tensorboard -- logdir=/tmp/mnist_convnet_model` or tf.Estimator collect all summaries automatically in `*/tmp/mnist_convnet_model` directory and I can just call `tensorboard -- logdir=/tmp/mnist_convnet_model`?
2. If I have to write `tf.summary()` could you answer me, should I insert in code `tf summary merge_all()` in the code and in what piece of code?

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)


def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
  """Model function for CNN."""
  # Input Layer
  input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 28, 28, 1])

  # Convolutional Layer #1
  conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=input_layer,
      filters=32,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Pooling Layer #1
  pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

  # Convolutional Layer #2
  conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=pool1,
      filters=64,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Pooling Layer #2
  pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

  # Flatten tensor into a batch of vectors
  pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])

  # Dense Layer
  dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Add dropout operation; 0.6 probability that element will be kept
  dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
      inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

  # Logits layer
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 1024]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 10]
  logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

  predictions = {
      # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
      "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
      # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
      # `logging_hook`.
      "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
  }
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

  # Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
  loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)

  # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

  # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
  eval_metric_ops = {
      "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
          labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


def main(unused_argv):
  # Load training and eval data
  mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
  train_data = mnist.train.images  # Returns np.array
  train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
  eval_data = mnist.test.images  # Returns np.array
  eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)

  # Create the Estimator
  mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model")

  # Set up logging for predictions
  # Log the values in the "Softmax" tensor with label "probabilities"
  tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
  logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
      tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

  # Train the model
  train_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": train_data},
      y=train_labels,
      batch_size=100,
      num_epochs=None,
      shuffle=True)
  mnist_classifier.train(
      input_fn=train_input_fn,
      steps=20000,
      hooks=[logging_hook])

  # Evaluate the model and print results
  eval_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": eval_data}, y=eval_labels, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
  eval_results = mnist_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
  print(eval_results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, You just need to specify `tf.summary.scalar()`, `tf.summary.histogram()` or `tf.summary.image()` anywhere in the code. You can use histogram summary in the following way to capture all weights and biases

```
for value in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES):
    tf.summary.histogram(value.name, value)
```

As for updatable metrics summary, e.g. accuracy of f1 score, you need to wrap it in `eval_metric_ops` and pass to `tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec`

```
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predictions)
    eval_metric_ops = {'accuracy': accuracy}
```

1. You can just call tensorboard with the same dir you specified during training.
2. You don't need to use `tf.summary.merge_all()`